# About the classification of linear autonomic differential equations of the plane.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, visualization

For a linear autonomic differential equation of the plane
$$\dot x = Ax,$$
with $A ∈ \operatorname{Mat}_{2×2} (ℝ)$, say we have a fundamental matrix $Φ \colon ℝ → \operatorname{Mat}_{2×2} (ℝ)$, that is an invertible solution to the differential equation
$$\dot X = A X$$
as an equation on $\operatorname{Mat}_{2×2} (ℝ)$.

If $Φ$ is conjugate over $ℂ$ to some $Ψ \colon ℝ → \operatorname{Mat}_{2×2} (ℂ)$ with
$$Ψ = \begin{bmatrix}\exp λ t & 0 \\ 0 & \exp \overline λ t \end{bmatrix}$$
for some $λ ∈ ℂ$ (and $λ \notin ℝ$), how can we deduce something about the quality of $Φ$?

I mean, if I could think visually in four dimension, it would be pretty clear how the solutions
$$\begin{bmatrix} \exp λ t \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \exp \overline λ t\end{bmatrix}$$
would look like. And I know that $\exp λt$ and $\exp \overline λ t$ in $ℂ$ “pretty much look like” rotations.

But how can I deduce from this that the solutions in $Φ$ “pretty much look like” rotations as well?

Comment: If $\Phi$ is conjugate over $\mathbb{C}$ to some $\Psi$ of such form, then it is conjugate over $\mathbb{R}$ to some $\hat{\Psi}$ which equals $e^{{\rm Re}  \lambda \cdot t}\begin{bmatrix}\cos {\rm Im} \lambda t & - \sin {\rm Im} \lambda t \\ \sin {\rm Im} \lambda t & \cos {\rm Im} \lambda t \end{bmatrix}$ :)

Comment: @Evgeny Hm, I knew this already. Putting two and two together sometimes … Anyway, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!